# How to install Windows on PC using laptop's monitor and keyboard?

Tags: windows, desktop-computer

I want to build a Windows PC which I will access remotely through Remote Desktop. I wonder if there is any method to use my laptop's monitor and keyboard as the terminal instead of buying separate monitor and keyboard just for installing the Windows.

Comment: In theory: Yes. You could create an automated install script and run that. But if you have never done that before then the efficient solution is to borrow a monitor and keyboard.

Comment: Alternatives: Connect the servers disk to the laptop and install on that. Then sysprep and move the disk over. (though I am not 100% you get away with absolutely no keyboard input or with installing remote access software before sysprepping). Or if the server has remote access tools (HP Ilo, Dells DRAC, ...) then you could use those.

Answer (score 0):

As simply as described in your question this is not possible. You could use an install script or connect the disc to the laptop then run sysprep as already suggested. Your best bet is to get hold of at the very least a keyboard and monitor

Answer (score 0):

Instead of buying a monitor and a keyboard, you could buy the [Epihpan Systems KVM2USB](http://www.epiphan.com/products/kvm2usb/) for only $399.95 (free shipping).

Comment: Useful device. But the price is the price of a computer. Feel ripped off.

Comment: That was kinda' my point. The easiest and cheapest solution is a keyboard and monitor.